# Where to keep Microsoft Owin dlls in Asp.Net project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ddl, middleware, owin

I'm in the process of moving DLL's from my new Asp.Net MVC project to concerned layers. It follows three layered architecture. i have moved red bordered DLL's to my DAL(Data Access Layer Project in my solution) My doubt is. Where should i keep DLL's which no red bordered in image.

Edited: I'm Using 3 Layered Architecture. Presentation,Business and Data Access Layer

[Click here to view DLL Screen Shot used in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96AfL.png)

Answer (score 1):

Those are difficult to separate like your trying.  The Identity owin middleware or any middleware you want to use the identity usermanager would need all those dlls referenced.

Comment: Thank you @William. Shall i keep it in presentation layer itself.